# can't pass less or more than 2 args for methods passing to array of PyMethodDef

Tags: python, c++, pyobject

I am following this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) on extending c++ to python. As far as what was demonstrated there, the `PyObject *spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {...}` works fine when passing to array of `PyModuleDef` but if I want to add more args to `spam_system`, it results in an invaid conversation following

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘PyObject* (*)()’ {aka ‘_object* (*)()’} to ‘PyCFunction’ {aka ‘_object* (*)(_object*, _object*)’} [-fpermissive]
```

for more example, I want to define a method that takes no args, and returns a `PyLong_FromLong` from `long`/`int`

```cpp
PyObject test() {return PyLong_FromLong(1);}

static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    {"system",  spam_system, METH_VARARGS,
     "Execute a shell command."},
    {"test",  test , METH_NOARGS,
              //^ the error happens here 
     "test."},

   {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};
```

How can I define a method that takes no args or more than two args? (adding two args to `test` works fine).

Comment: You just have to force conversion to PyCFunction pointer. Write `{"test",  (PyCFunction)test , METH_NOARGS, "test."}`

Comment: wouldn't this have any consequences?

Comment: No, it is totally alright. That is what documentation says to do. I've being reading documentation regarding programming under C++ and found this and was also surprised, but in fact it worked. Also on the very first run you'll notice if it works or not. If it doesn't work then program will just crash because of corrupted stack (wrong function type corrupts stack in half of time), if it doesn't crash then it definitely will work correctly.

Comment: All alright, def need to try, What I'm  even more curious about is why does `test` remain `PyObject *` as long as there are two instances of `PyObject*` being passed and then becomes `PyCFunction`  if num of args is <=/>= 2?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's C++, which is more strict about function pointer casting than C, you'll have to cast to `(PyCFunction)`, or, IIRC, `(void*)` also works.